# Remove common in two list

Tags: python, list, set

I have problem with Python function uncommon(l1,l2) that takes two lists sorted in ascending order as arguments and returns the list of all elements that appear in exactly one of the two lists. The list returned should be in ascending order. All such elements should be listed only once, even if they appear multiple times in l1 or l2.

Thus, `uncommon([2,2,4],[1,3,3,4,5])` should return `[1,2,3,5]` while `uncommon([1,2,3],[1,1,2,3,3])` should return []

I have tried

```
def uncommon(l1,l2):
  sl1=set(l1)
  sl2=set(l2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using sets is a good start - sets have good logic regarding group operations.
If we think using venn diagrams we can see that "uncommon" elements are everything that is in the *Union* of the two lists minus the *intersection* of the two lists (the part in white is the intersection):
[image]

In python, this is called [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), and is built into sets:

```py
def uncommon(l1, l2):
    set1 = set(l1)
    set2 = set(l2)
    return sorted(set1.symmetric_difference(set2))


print(uncommon([2, 2, 4], [1, 3, 3, 4, 5]))  # [1, 2, 3, 5]
print(uncommon([2, 2, 4], [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 255]))  # [1, 2, 3, 5, 255]
print(uncommon([1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3, 3]))  # []
```

Comment: `set` doesn't retain order, the results should be sorted.

Comment: I've added a `sorted` keyword to the return statement.

Comment: A set can be sorted (because it's iterable) therefore no need to convert to a list. The argument passed to symmetric_difference can be a list so no need to construct set2. Thus *return sorted(set(l1).symmetric_difference(l2))* will suffice

Comment: great thaanks! I used xor operator.. I think sorted(set1.symmetric_difference(set2))  looks more better

Answer (score 0):

**To get the uncommon element from two lists remove the common elements from the union(list1+list2) of the two lists.**

```
def uncommon(l1,l2):
    l1 = set(l1)
    l2 = set(l2)
    return sorted(list(l1.union(l2) - (l1.intersection(l2))))


print(uncommon([2,2,4],[1,3,3,4,5]))
print(uncommon([1,2,3],[1,1,2,3,3]))
```

OUTPUT

```
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[]
```

Comment: Seems to fail for `uncommon([2,2,4],[1,3,3,4,5,256])` ;)

Comment: @mozway I get `[256, 1, 2, 3, 5]`. What you expected??

Comment: `set` doesn't retain order, the results should be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that doesn't require sorting (`O(n*logn)`), you can merge the sorted lists with [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) after removing the duplicates and intersections:

```
from heapq import merge

def uncommon(l1,l2):
    d1 = dict.fromkeys(l1)
    d2 = dict.fromkeys(l2)
    drop = set(d1).intersection(d2)
    return list(merge(*([x for x in d
                         if not x in drop]
                        for d in [d1, d2])))

uncommon([2,2,4], [1,3,3,4,5,256])
# [1, 2, 3, 5, 256]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def uncommon(l1,l2):
  sl1=set(l1)
  sl2=set(l2)
  return list(sl1^sl2)
```

---

Thanks for help! Actually i found a solution like this. What about this?

Answer (score -3):

The common elements are those contained in both lists. So first get rid of elements in list 1 that are also in list 2. Then get rid of elements in list 2 that are also in list 1.
Return the remaining elements.

```
def uncommon(l1, l2):
    d1=l1-l2
    d2=l2-l1
    return d1+d2
```

Comment: You can't do `list - list`

Comment: This will not work you can't subtract a list by a list